# Android: Application for different requirements and features

Tags: android, build, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

Using [build variant](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) in Android we can support different flavors.
I need to develop an application where I am supporting different clients. Each client needs are a little different.

However, the basic data, network call class etc are same for all clients.
How can I ensure partial code of my application remains same for all flavors?

This will help in maintaining one repository for all common classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how build variant works.

**Each client needs are a little different is a vague statement**

Imagine you have an application which has different screen's for different countries. But major functionalities are the same.

Now using build variants you can make different flavors

**1) For country one** : This will have screens designed specific to country one

**2) For country two** : This will have screens designed specific to country two

**3) Common part** : All the common business logic can be put under your common package

While project is build, the common part is considered and specific flavor too becomes part of `flavorXX.apk`

```
productFlavors {

        employee {
            applicationId "com.myapp.employee"
        }
        driver {
            applicationId "com.myapp.driver"
        }
        asset {
            applicationId "com.myapp.asset"
        }
        vehicle {
            applicationId "com.myapp.vehicle"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        asset {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/asset/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        driver {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/driver/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        employee {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/employee/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        vehicle {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/vehicle/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
```

In the above example , I am having different flavors of same application. Inorder to split accordingly **you need to understand which part of your app goes into specific flavor and which can be kept common.** Go through below links for more details.

[Understanding Product Flavors reference link 1](http://www.androidauthority.com/building-multiple-flavors-android-app-706436/)

[Understanding Product Flavors reference link 2](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1091557/android-product-flavors-and-configuration)