# How to keep app data when you develop an app and also use it from the store

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing an application on my personal Android phone.

I deployed my app on the store (as a closed alpha).

When I use my app from the store and then, when I get the app in debug from my dev computer, Android Studio indicates that the app versions are incompatible.

Thus the version from the app store has to be removed with all its data.

Is there a way to keep the data?

Is it possible to have two versions of my app on my phone?

Comment: No way. if you're device has debug build than you must update with debug built. same for release built

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the debug version a different package name. That way you can have the release build (from the Play Store) and the debug build (directly from Android Studio) both on the same device at the same time. The data that the two versions use will be different however, as the data is private for each version of the app.

To give the debug version a different package name, add this to the project level build.gradle, in the `android` section of the file:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The debug build is signed by Android studio with `debug keystore`. Where as the app store release build should be signed with `Release keystore` while signing.

Now both will obviously vary. But as @M D said its not possible to keep both the app. `As both are having common parameters like package name and other factors`

But using build flavours you can have application's **which will vary with package names** for `debug` and `release` versions. Check out my answer for [Android Build Variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841484/android-application-for-different-requirements-and-features/43841978#43841978)

Comment: Both answers are useful and complementary. Hence I shared the rewards :) Thanks!

Comment: @unludo Happy Coding !